# How to get rid of Adobe Scene7 related errors in AEM error.log?

Tags: aem, osgi-bundle, day-cq, scene7

We are no longer using the adobe scene7 integration in our application, so I disabled the scene7 bundles using [OSGi configuration](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/osgi-disabler.html), even after doing that I still see a scene7 related error in my error log such as below. Can I also disable the bundle **com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-webservice-support** in order to avoid the errors? or is there any other way to avoid this error? we are using AEM 6.0

```
*ERROR* [pool-9-thread-1] com.day.cq.wcm.webservicesupport.impl.statistics.ServicesStatisticsServiceImpl Saving statistics on /etc/cloudservices/scene7 failed.
javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: Node with path /etc/cloudservices/scene7 does not exist.
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl.getNode(SessionImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.base.SessionProxyHandler$SessionProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SessionProxyHandler.java:113)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.webservicesupport.impl.statistics.ServicesStatisticsServiceImpl.getSubNode(ServicesStatisticsServiceImpl.java:405)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.webservicesupport.impl.statistics.ServicesStatisticsServiceImpl.writeScene7Stats(ServicesStatisticsServiceImpl.java:325)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.webservicesupport.impl.statistics.ServicesStatisticsServiceImpl.updateStats(ServicesStatisticsServiceImpl.java:207)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.webservicesupport.impl.statistics.ServicesStatisticsJob.run(ServicesStatisticsJob.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzJobExecutor.execute(QuartzJobExecutor.java:105)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-webservice-support bundle will affect other cloud configurations setup in that environment as well. To stop logs from getting clogged up, you can probably retain just the cloud config for scene 7 in /etc/cloudservices and remove all other configs/bundles your application is using to integrate with scene 7.

Comment: Hi Subhash like you said I can't disable the bundle as it affects other cloud configs, retaining just the scene7 config might help but not sure how to do that. Can you elaborate on how to do that?